# No option to set the list-view of folders and files on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I've just formatted my laptop to Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (was using it too but I'm doing a fresh format) and now it seems I have no way to set the files and folders to show them as a list, while I could it before formatting. This is how the Preferences menu looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try the Nautilus buttons in the toolbar?

Comment: yep, not showing there too, weird thing is it was working before formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: The 'four squares' and 'two squares with horizontal lines besides them' in the folder window switch between icon view or list view.]

The 'four squares' and 'two squares with horizontal lines besides them' in the folder window switch between icon view or list view.

Comment: oh well, didn't know that was the way now, thank you!